# How do I get my elixir tests concerning paths to work on mac and in dropbox?

Tags: macos, path, elixir, dropbox

I am making a program that will identify videos in non-video folders and non-videos in video folders all inside a dropbox folder, the issue is that I am working on a windows system and the client has a mac.  The last time I had the client test the program the tests failed because of some issue around the formats_path/2 and identifies_path_type_and_formats/1.  I have minimal experience with Unix paths so I have made some changes around what I do understand but would love help to get the tests to work on a mac and any issues I haven't run into around dropbox.  Here is the github link https://github.com/TinyBFG/erovf.

Comment: I can't speak to much on the Windows side of the world, but generally with file-paths I would avoid relative paths (e.g. the `../`) and instead leverage the `app_dir`, e.g. `Application.app_dir(:erovf, ["path", "to", "files"])` to locate a directory.  Maybe you can simplify this to a single path evaluation instead of a list of them.

Comment: So I figured out how to remove relative paths completely, but with the tests I am gonna have issues since I need to rely on relative paths for those to work.  Any advice on those?

Comment: When you run `mix test`, keep in mind that paths are relative to where you run the command (i.e. to the root of your repo) and not to a file, so it's rare that you'll need to use `..` unless you are pointing to directories outside of your repository (which wouldn't be great for testing anyway).  Not sure if this package would be any help: https://hexdocs.pm/xfile/ -- it can apply a function or a regular expression to filter files from recursive directories.